# Need to fetch the records with the status code provided

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to fetch the records from the table.
Below is the conditions which i need to follow.

Table:

```
SID,Name,Status
1,abc,'T'
1,abc,'R'
2,xyz,'T'
3,acd,'R'
```

I need to fetch the records with status code only 'R'.
I need to get the SID 3.

Here i can have more status code like 'A','P','E'.

I need to fetch the records only having the status code 'R' and if any user is having two status codes which includes 'R', then i dont fetch the record in the output.

Could anyone please help me writing the query.

Thanks,
Rishi.

Comment: Do you need the whole row, or only the `SID`?

Comment: What do you mean "don't fetch the record in the output"?

Comment: i dont want the records who are having two status codes.
i want only the records which are having only 'R' as status.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
SELECT [SID]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY [SID]
HAVING MIN([Status]) = MAX([Status])
AND MIN([Status]) = 'R';
```

Comment: either you can read minds or are really making a big guess at what the OP wants

Comment: Or maybe I can try to understand what's being asked: "I need to fetch the records with status code **only** 'R'.". Looking at the sample data, and the desired result it's not really a **big** guess

Comment: ha, your right! you actually could read that question, +1 for you.